# Yii multi-language folder structure

Tags: php, yii

So I am using an existing Yii project where the folder layout deviates from "standard" Yii, see below image:

[image]

Now I need to add the message folder for the languages, where would I put it? It doesn't work where it is, see image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So found the solution, you have to force langauge translation in config/main.php

```
'messages' => array(
   'basePath' => Yiibase::getPathOfAlias('site.frontend.messages'),
   'forceTranslation' => TRUE
),
```

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPhpMessageSource#basePath-detail). You can put it anywhere that suits you, and in the app config file, you can set the path where the messages component will look for message files:

```
<?php

return array(
  // ...
  'messages' => array(
    'basePath' => __DIR__ . '/../../messages',
  ),
  // ...
);
```

Comment: Good thinking, but `Property "BaseWebApplication.messages" is read only.`

Comment: Which version of Yii are you using? That works just fine for me.

Comment: it has to be under components, but the language text still isn't printing. Is there a way to view the path?

Comment: The documentation describes what path is used by default - `protected/messages`.

Comment: Yeah, but I set it like you advised, yet it still isn't working, how can I test this further?